# Best method of repairing plastic door frame

Tags: door-frame

I dropped a canister going through the outside patio doorway and the corner chipped away the plastic door frame. I see that these frames are all one piece and expensive and time consuming to replace. Is there a way to repair this? I tried using bi-component glue, but that turned yellow when dried. I was thinking of cutting a piece from an inconspicuous area and gluing it inside. Would there be a way to repair this without replacing the entire door frame?

[image]

Comment: I don't suppose you were lucky enough for the piece to break off whole?

Answer (score 3):

I personally do not think a PVC cement will give satisfactory results. I would probably:

1) find a thin gauge aluminum channel that fits over the broken frame, deep enough to cover the gouge, spray paint it to match, and silicone it down over the length of the frame. Or,

2) use automotive body filler, plane and sand to blend, than spray prime and paint the entire lower frame (perhaps this is similar to the "bond and fill" product you found, if so give it a try!)

Answer (score 1):

That looks to my eye - right or wrong - like a vinyl (PVC) frame, so I think you may be able to get PVC cement to work OK there. You may need to do a bunch of trimming after the cement has set up to get it back to something approximating flat & straight, though.

If you don't still have the missing piece(s), you may be able to reconstruct with plastic wrung from PVC pipe - if you apply heat carefully, you can often get the curvature of the pipe to flatten out at around the boiling point of water. That'd give you flat stock to carefully shape into a replacement patch. Flatten enough for several runs at this thing, of course - one errant swipe with a file and it's scarred for good. With really careful work, you may be able to make that fix virtually invisible.

EDIT: Before you go melting down PVC pipe to make the patch, though, try a little dab of PVC cement on the inside of that gap... applied with a Q-tip... to see if it "likes" the plastic in question. If it doesn't, we'll have to find a different solution altogether.